# How can we set Vertical TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I need Vertical Text in text TextView is there any property fir this ?
please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take an imageview set the background look like textview, and set the height & width manually

Comment: then how can set text dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a vertical `LinearLayout` and set your `TextView`'s width to a specific width.