# android text view text in vertical direction

Tags: android, text, textview, rotation

I have a `Textview` in which i am showing text `12345` now i want to show text

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I tried `rotation` but it rotate my text and not giving the exact look.
I don't want to place \n tag in `character`.
I don't want customization.

Comment: Have you had a look at these suggestions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773693/how-can-we-set-vertical-textview

Comment: Check this: [Vertical (rotated) label in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could extend `TextView` to your custom `VerticalTextView` and override `setText()`     method. In `setText` implementation you could iterate through text and modify it inserting linebreaks `\n`. After you finish just set result value to your view.

Comment: can you give me ideas or code which override setText() method.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a `TextWatcher` if you just want to override `setText`, and it could append the `\n` to each character that is added to the `TextView`