# How to set text in cross instead of horizontal in android?

Tags: android, textview

In layout there is textview. And i want to show the text in some angle(in cross) instead of horizontal. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using Xml:

```
<TextView 
        ...
        android:rotation="45" />
```

Using Code:

```
myTextView.setRotation(45f);
```

For API 10 and below, must be done through code:

```
RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(45f, 45f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animation.setDuration(1);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
myTextView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Note that this is not available before Android 3.0 (API 11).

Comment: Ya. I am making application for Android 2.2 , Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very similar question to a previous post.   Check out the accepted answer here:  [android text view text in vertical direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604932/android-text-view-text-in-vertical-direction)

I don't believe there's an "easy" way to do it without some customization of the textview class.

Comment: I don't want text in vertical. I want in cross.