# Writing text vertically

Tags: android, textview

I have a graph and I want to show the   name of the axis vertically. But how do I write it vertically along the y-axis ? Tried using `textview.setRotation(270)` but had problems with its width as the width was not getting decreased when it was in vertical.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write vertically in a textview in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888780/is-it-possible-to-write-vertically-in-a-textview-in-android) and [android text view text in vertical direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604932/android-text-view-text-in-vertical-direction) and [How can we set Vertical TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773693/how-can-we-set-vertical-textview)

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to add the "\n" (newline) character after each character taken from the `TextView`. There are other methods, but this one is the simplest. You might also want to consider setting it to be multiline too.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is to subclass `TextView` and override its `onDraw` method

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
    canvas.rotate(-90);
    Layout layout = getLayout();
    if (layout != null)
        layout.draw(canvas);
   canvas.restore();
}
```